# Salesforce Barcode API Testing and Debugging

Tags: lightning-web-components, debugging, barcode

I am working with the Salesforce Barcode Scanner API for continuous scanning.
For some reason it just keeps resetting and exiting the scan mode, even using the original [example](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.use_barcodescanner_example_continuous).

Could you please tell, how can I literally debug it in the mobile application and see what's wrong with it, since the emulator doesn't support the Barcode functionality?

Has Anyone of you seen such behavior while using the Barcode API?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried the [Single Scan](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.use_barcodescanner_example) mode first? With what results? I've just given it a try. Scanning some bar codes, the app crashed, although I had not to re-login. Scanning QR codes it suddenly worked. Have you made sure you scan any of the [supported bar code types](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.use_barcodescanner_compatibility)? The app might just have terrible error handling in case of unsupported input.

Comment: Hey @FelixvanHove, yep, I tried the single scan it works on some of the devices. Samsung-only, when it comes to the Android stack. Samsungs can handle QR single scan, but multiple scans are just a nightmare. What I eventually did is added a modal window after every single scan with "continue option" to re-init the scanner, so there would be no need to use the multiscan :)

Comment: Thx for getting back! Have you found a way to debug the scan process? In that case, it would be nice if you posted this as an answer - I'd be curious!

Comment: @FelixvanHove, tbh - just some good-old alert-debugging with error codes. However, the scanner API itself throws very generic exceptions like "unexpected error while trying to scan barcode" or something similar. Well, it is still technically in beta...